# Spring and Hibernate Restful webservice configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

### **Please any help on this**

I would like to ask your help on this, I configured a project in `Netbeans` to build a Restful Webservice with `Spring MVC` and `Hibernate` to connect to the database.

The problem is that I don't know how to configure the controller to execute and return the `JSON`.

I already developed my Data Access Layer, my service and my controller, but I don't know how to configure the project to execute: `http:localhost:8080/project/user` for example.

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="ServiceLayer.Controller"/>

</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject.UserDAO ServiceLayer.Service.UserService.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject.UserDAO ServiceLayer.Service.UserService.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ServiceLayer.Service.UserService ServiceLayer.Controller.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject.UserDAO ServiceLayer.Service.UserService.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ServiceLayer.Service.UserService ServiceLayer.Controller.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject.UserDAO ServiceLayer.Service.UserService.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ServiceLayer.Service.UserService ServiceLayer.Controller.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject.UserDAO ServiceLayer.Service.UserService.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I will appreciate a lot your help.

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: You have everything required, just run the project on a Servlet container like Tomcat and use Postman or any Rest Client to access the URL to see the response JSON. Note you might have to set Accepts and Content-Type headers to application/json .

Comment: Thanks @M4ver1k, I want to see the json in the browser, could you help me with the url structure to do that, because I tried but never get the result.

Comment: for example I tried this: `http://localhost:8080/SignaSafeProject/usercontroller/user/` and `http://localhost:8080/SignaSafeProject/user`, but I always get error 404

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/SignaSafeProject/usercontroller/user/` is not mapped to anything in above controller but `http://localhost:8080/SignaSafeProject/user` should work. Are u seeing any exception in the console on application startup ?

Comment: No i don't get any error.. I got this: HTTP Status 404 - /SignaSafeProject/user, I think I miss something in the web.xml or in any xml configuration

Comment: Do I have to configure anything in the applicationContext.xml or in the web.xml, a bean or something referring the user controller class?

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera Can you try removing the trailing `/` in the `RequestMapping(value = "/user/"`as in `RequestMapping(value = "/user"` and try with following URL `http://localhost:8080/SignaSafeProject/usercontroller/user.json`.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, thanks for your comment but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera Are you seeing  any exceptions in your server logs during deployment? post your web.xml as well.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu thanks, I added the web.xml code

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera dispatcherServlet is mapped to `*.htm`. Instead can you map it to `/` and try.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu thanks again, now I think it is working but I'm getting error 500, I added the stack error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103555/discussion-between-madhusudana-reddy-sunnapu-and-jose-raul-perera).

Answer (score 0):

This is not straight answer to your question. But it may help in longer run.

Why don't you make your application as [spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) application. It will make your application simpler. You don't need to configure web.xml, deploy your war and so on. May be you can get started with [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)
Complete documentation can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

Comment: Thanks Samuel, I read the article and it's look good, however I will need to develop a few features with JSF, so I need to build the JSF pages plus a Restful services for API, that's why I decided to structure the project in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could always start the application in debug mode from the IDE and see the logs for which URL Mappings are being registered on to your controller handlers. On a different note :

- Then, there is also this in the stacktrace : `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ServiceLayer.Service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies` which points to a possible configuration requirement for scanning components. So please adjust your `<context:component-scan>` tag to include the packages containing your beans.
  As an example : `<context:component-scan base-package="ServiceLayer.Service, ServiceLayer.Controller, ServiceLayer.Dao" />`
- Also, your web.xml maps `*.htm` to your dispatcher, so if you want
  your dispatcher to receive all the requests - you might want to
  change that to `/` or `/*` based on how you want it to operate.
  Otherwise, only requests like `http:localhost:8080/project/user.htm`
  will be processed, and not the type of requests that you intend to
  process which is mentioned as this `http:localhost:8080/project/user`
  in the question.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Gyanapriya, it solve the problem partially, because I'm getting a different error, I will post the new error...